# Concatenating dataframes vertically using Python

Tags: python, pandas

When concatenating 10 dataframes vertically I get one extra index column added with the column name "null".

The way I use the concat function is:

```
concData = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10], axis="columns", ignore_index=True)
```

after this I set the column names as:

```
concData.columns = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5', 'name6', 'name7', 'name8', 'name9', 'name10']

print(concData.keys())
```

the print statement shows

```
Index(['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5', 'name6',
       'name7', 'name8', 'name9', 'name10'],
      dtype='object')
```

from my understanding, the "ignore_index=True" when concatenating should remove the column called "null" and all it's rows.
I have also tried to use the line below right after concData.columns with the same result:

```
concData = concData.reset_index(drop=True)
```

How to drop the extra index column which is added after pd.concat?

Comment: The "null" column is not coming from concat, it should have been in one of your dataframes.

Comment: @SomeDude Yeah you are right, I do have the "null" column right before the concat.

The dataframe comes from a list, when printing the list I get the below result:
['code1', 'code2', 'code3']
<class 'list'>

then I make a dataframe out of this list by:
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)

I then write the df1 to a excel file, is it during this process the "null" column is created? cos I can not see it when printing in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by having too many `NaN`  in the merged DataFrames

exp:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c': 1, 'd': np.nan,'e':np.nan},index=[0,1,2])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': 3, 'b': 4,'c':5},index=[0,1,2])
>>> pd.concat([df,df2],axis='columns',ignore_index=True)

#Output:

   0  1  2  3   4   5
0  3  4  5  1 NaN NaN
1  3  4  5  1 NaN NaN
2  3  4  5  1 NaN NaN
```

If you had more data you would get a dataset with less or no `NaN` data

exp :

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c': 1, 'd': 2,'e':6},index=[0,1,2])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': 3, 'b': 4,'c':5},index=[0,1,2])
>>> pd.concat([df,df2],axis='columns',ignore_index=True)

#Output:

   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  3  4  5  1  2  6
1  3  4  5  1  2  6
2  3  4  5  1  2  6
```

**[EDIT]**

Why `pd.ExcelWriter` is adding null column i dont know either but here some solution :

```
#creating subset 
df1 = df[['A']]  

#Writing excel with xlsxwriter engine 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('f_name.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter',options={'nan_inf_to_errors': True})  

#Convert dataframe to excel with NaNs replace with 0s
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='PnL', na_rep=0)
```

or

```
df = df.fillna(0) #before adding excel
```

this will provide you to get rid of `NaN`s

Comment: But I do not have many NaN, as in my last post the "null" column is created before the concat

Comment: what was your process before concat?

Comment: pd.ExcelWriter was adding the "null" column after some investigation, I am not sure why and where in the write to excel functionality it is done. Using the "to_excel" function instead did not add a "null" column.

Comment: Edited, Does it helpful?